# Rails4 - validates_format_of :user_name.downcase not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in a model I'm validating new users and attempting to downcase their user name before it's saved.

I thought this would work:

```
 validates_format_of :user_name.downcase,:with => /\A[0-9a-zA-Z]*\z/
```

Unfortunately it doesn't.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a custom setter

```
def user_name=(value)
  self[:user_name] = value.downcase
end
```

that way you are sure that you will always have a downcased string in user_name when you assign any string to it

What's wrong in your code is that :user_name.downcase is actually the string "user_name" (user_name symbol, to_s, downcase), and also your regex matches capital letter

change it to:

```
validates_format_of :user_name,:with => /\A[0-9a-z]*\z/
```

Comment: Thanks man. I love rails, but sometimes the rails magic (and it's ability to do something in 27 different ways) really makes me crazy. Also, nice one on the regex, I totally missed it.

Comment: For your initial requirement, you only need the validation and there's really a few ways to do that, you only missed the A-Z on the regexp. The custom setter is just a suggestion, it might not fit every escenario, I just think it might fit yours.

Comment: No that's totally what I wanted. I'm tired of this being an issue, I want all user names to be lower case all the time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these two tasks with `validates_format_of` and `before_save` callback

First validate the format of `user_name` and then in a `before_save` callback downcase it.

```
validates_format_of :user_name, with: /\A[0-9a-zA-Z]+\z/
before_save :downcase_user_name

private

def downcase_user_name
  self.user_name = user_name.downcase
end
```

Comment: before_save :downcase_user_name