# Setting self variables in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a method in my Rails User model that looks like this:

```
def prep_data
  if email.present?
    self.email = email.downcase
  end

  if username.present?
    self.username = username.downcase
  end
  puts "***********************"
  puts self.email
  puts self.inspect
  puts "***********************"   
end
```

When I run this, I'm getting:

```
***********************
john@me.com
#<User id: nil, username: nil, email: nil, password_salt: nil, password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
***********************
```

I'm at a loss to explain why self.email seems to be set, but then when I inspect self, it is nil. This is also causing the object to not save because it's nil. A more complete version of the log is

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"7ocuB7GiyPjMZ84SHKo9CDSPjY8uOdtDc5A9wr+stzTPrIHnvfxAkdp1HxWActd07ZWzJVEBH43A3V/4sX1ixg==", "user"=>{"username"=>"John", "email"=>"John@me.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
***********************
john@me.com
#<User id: nil, username: nil, email: nil, password_salt: nil, password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
***********************
***********************
john@me.com
#<User id: nil, username: nil, email: nil, password_salt: "$2a$10$T92qOVBwjGm4t550POLVHu", password_digest: "$2a$10$T92qOVBwjGm4t550POLVHuXhss6lniJJekxMbeKR/yU...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
***********************
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'john' LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'john@me.com' LIMIT 1
SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("password_salt", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["password_salt", "$2a$10$T92qOVBwjGm4t550POLVHu"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$T92qOVBwjGm4t550POLVHuXhss6lniJJekxMbeKR/yU.79uMqtZJa"], ["created_at", "2016-09-23 17:51:31.692923"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-23 17:51:31.692923"]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: users.username: INSERT INTO "users" ("password_salt", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The end goal is to get this to actually save. You can see that when rails does the Insert, username and email are nil, but I can tell from the debug puts statements that the email and username exist and are getting at least to the validation. That said, even it I remove the validation completely, I have this problem.

Comment: How do you know email is present?

Comment: That's so weird, something else is messing with your code. I see you are only sanitizing user values, you might want to do that inside custom setters, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665490/rails4-validates-format-of-user-name-downcase-not-working/39666066#39666066. You should try to solve this particular issue even if you don't need to using the custom setters because it will explode you somewhere else later though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
self.email.downcase! if email.present?
```

Comment: I get the same result whether it's like this or as I have it above.

Comment: 'User exist' in the log - may be that you have some unique constraint on email?

Answer (score 0):

@arieljuod solved this for me by recommending that I use custom setters instead of trying to change things before validation. Problem solved although I don't fully understand why the other way didn't work even if it wasn't "best"

```
def username=(value)
  self[:username] = value.downcase
end

def email=(value)
  self[:email] = value.downcase
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call save on the model.  So just call self.save on the model.

Comment: no, it is not the point, `inspect` should show unsaved fields

Comment: Did you verify that the email is valid?  What happens when you call self.valid?  Also see what happens if you call self.save!

Comment: You might want to try this and see what happens.

Comment: I am calling save on the model. Calling save on the model fails because email is nil - hence this post. This function is called before_validation so none of the validation rules should have anything to do with it. I would expect that since self.email displays something, it would be set when I inspect self.